# use of partial in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partial

I wanted to manage the root page through application.html.erb to insert a partial _header.html.erb for the header bar and a partial _footer.html.erb 
for the footer bar and in the other pages I would like to enter another partial _sidebar.html.erb  for the sidebar...how can i do? Sidebar must not be present in the homepage (root). 
I have to handle this problem for layout in the application.html.erb page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to handle this using layouts. The default one is application.html.erb.

Here is an example of your problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <%= render :partial => 'layouts/common_header' %>
  <body>
    <%=  render :partial => 'layouts/top_menu' %>
    <div id='container-fluid'>
      <div id='sidebar'>
        <%= render :partial => 'layouts/sidebar' %>
      </div>
      <div id='content'>
        <%= yield %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have a layout that uses partials for the header, the navbar, the sidebar.

Comment: Is sidebar present in your home page?

Comment: in my home page should not be present...the sidebar is present only for the other pages different  different from the homepage

Comment: Take a look at this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content_for-method

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I made a helper method in LayoutsHelper like so:

```
def sidebar(state)
    @sidebar = state
end
```

You can call that method in the view on a page you don't want the sidebar to showup on `<% sidebar false %>`

And then in your `application.html.erb`, you can use `unless` to show the sidebar unless the @sidebar variable is set to false:

```
<% unless @sidebar == false %>
    <div class="sidebar">some stuff</div>
<% end %>
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do it, but that's worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having the sidebar in you main page, issue:

```
render :layout => false
```

in the controller and add the header and footer partials to your `index.html.erb` file.